# I want to understand the role of recursion in merge sort

Tags: recursion, mergesort

/*I got this code snippet from an online website: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/merge_sort_program_in_c.htm
I know the principle of recursion but I can't seem to understand the recursion in merge sort 
*/

```
  void sort(int low, int high) 
{  
  int mid;

 if(low < high) 

{
  mid = (low + high) / 2;
  sort(low,  mid); Pls explain 
  sort(mid+1, high); Pls explain 
  merging(low, mid, high);
}

else 
{ 
  return;

}   

}
```

Comment: The idea is to sort the left side of the array, and then the right side, and then merge them by comparing the leftmost item from the left side, and the leftmost item from the right side.
The wikipedia page has an animation that shows how it is done, and it is really nice:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: But how does these recursive method work mid = (low + high) / 2;
  sort(low,  mid);